# Split number thousand java

Tags: java, regex, formatting

I want to split some `String` by adding some commas in it.
For example :

```
"1234" => "1,234"
"12345" => "12,345"
"123456" => "123,456"
"1234567" => "1,234,567"
"12345678" => "12,345,678"
"123456789" => "123,456,789"
```

I can have such a huge String like "123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789"

Currently, I use this code with `DecimalFormat` but because I cast into double, my number is limited to the range of Double so I need to find another way to avoid this range. I receive a `String` and I want to parse it like a String, not a number (`Integer`, `Double`). I think I can use regex or something like this, but I don't know how to do it.

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(',');
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###", symbols);
formattedStr = df.format(Double.parseDouble(str));
```

Comment: Only integer numbers?

Comment: Are you later only dispalying these numbers, or are you using them ?

Comment: yes but I can have a big number over double's range like 123456789123456789123456789. That's why I need to change. @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: Maybe look into the BigInteger class first. When your integer values are too big for long or int, double isn't a good solution.

Comment: Iterate backwards over the String and insert a comma after every third character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use a `BigInteger` as mentioned in other answers, or use a regular expression as follows:

```
public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String s = "12345678912345678912345678";
         String formatted = s.replaceAll("(\\d)(?=(\\d{3})+$)", "$1,");
         System.out.println(formatted); // 12,345,678,912,345,678,912,345,678
     }
}
```

The expression will append a comma after all digits that are followed by at least one group of 3 digits.

Answer (score 1):

To have such huge numbers, you will have to use **BigInteger** or **BigDecimal**. This snippet should help you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger integer = BigInteger.valueOf(60000);

    String result = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(
        integer);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output: 60,000

Good luck.

Comment: I receive a Striing. How can I create a BigInteger from a String ?

Comment: `new BigInteger(str)`

Comment: It is possible. Using the constructor BigInteger(String val) will translate the number representation of the String to BigInteger. Please explore java documentation for more information.